# How to resolve 'Unexpected end of JSON input' using typed-azure-functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am using azure functions core tools from a cloned repository with a shopify microservice. The project setup has these steps:  
`npm install` 
`npm run build`

`npm run typed-az-func -- push` 
`npm run typed-az-func -- push --execute` 
`npm run typed-az-func -- pull`

I was logged in on azure using the azure-cli. In the last command (`npm run typed-az-func -- pull`), I've encountered some errors:
[Command errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCM6P.png)

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
and installed Azure Function Core Tools from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v3%2Clinux%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda

Answer (score 0):

There's a high chance that your `npm` cache been damaged.

Try `npm cache clean --force` command before npm run command and this should resolve the issue.